# Sending a value instead of a key from an select list in the form

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, collections

Below is the code to remove duplicate values from the field and return only one value.

**Array value in Controller**

```
$job_types = DB::table('jobs')->pluck('job_type')
            ->unique(function ($item){
                return $item;
            });
```

Below creates a Select List using the extracted array from the field.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4" id="job_type">
    {!! Form::label('job_type', 'Emne:') !!}

    {!! Form::select('job_type', $job_types, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'job_type']) !!}
</div>
```

[image]

Above image is my select list in the form.
I try to send a selected value instead of a key in the form at Laravel.

but, always they returned a key instead of a value as below image(DB screen shot) when I selected a value in the select list.
Which part of the code is wrong?

[image]

'job_types' collection is as below.

[image]

Comment: use lists('TEXTNAME', "id")

Comment: @Bugfixer, could you tell me more detail? thanks

Comment: did u deal with it?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski, no still trying....thanks:(

Comment: what is wrong in my solution?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski, it still get just Key instead of value when list selected.:(

Answer (score 0):

As a `$job_types` which is id set `$job_types` as it real name.

So u must rebuild:

```
return $item->name; // name is the proper value from your database

$job_types = DB::table('jobs')->pluck('job_type')
            ->unique(function ($item){
                return $item->name;
            });
```

Be sure that you use pluck in proper way:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck

Comment: ,I got error as `Trying to get property of non-object`, thanks.

Comment: Look, i do not know your database structure. So the '$item->name' is just example. Get proper variable from your table.

Comment: I think it not above codes error, it's how to post data after date selected list. so I have to modify store() in my Controller, :) thanks

Comment: Could you check added image in the bottom of my question? Collection as that, how could I get the value instead of key? thanks.